# Random float generator function stopped working in C

Tags: c, random, numbers, generator

I have this random number function I created in C:

```
/************************************************************************

Function:      randomNumber

Description:    Generates a random float number between 0.0 and a given max

*************************************************************************/
float randomNumber(float max) {
    float x = ((float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX)) * max;
    return x;
}
```

if I call it using:

```
randomNumber(1.0);
```

I get the number 0.00125125889 every single time.

I have used it many times in the past with other programs/assignments but it is not working with this current program I am writing and I am not sure why. I tried calling srand(time(NULL)) before calling rand() (I never had to do this in my other programs) and it still doesn't work properly. maybe it might be the #defines I am using but I don't see how they would relate to the rand functions.

I would be greatly thankful if someone could help me figure out why it's not working.

EDIT:

it seems to work when it is inside a for loop, why doesn't it work outside?

Comment: Looks fine here: http://ideone.com/hFI5gL.  Please provide a complete test case ;)

Comment: it seems to only work inside a for loop, is there any way to make it work outside?

Comment: Please add the code for a complete program that demonstrates it not working outside a loop.

Comment: I'd expect it to be fixed by calling `srand(time(NULL))` before `rand()`. I don't know what the rest of the code looks like, but you might also want to have a look on this one about `srand()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7343909/2304215

Comment: Be sure to call `calling srand((unsigned) time(NULL))` only _once_ in your code.  Maybe in `main()`.

Comment: thanks everybody! chux, i think that was my issue.

Comment: Sounds like you're re-seeding.